# How force bing logo to bottom quickmap service

Tags: qgis, legal, quickmapservices

I'm trying to compose a map on QGIS 2.14.6 using Bing Satellite basemap with quickmap service plugin.

However, contrary to other basemaps like OSM Mapnik, I am not able to force showing bing logo to bottom of a map.

Going through Bing Satellite layer's properties I have switched on the box "place the credit on bottom right corner".

Does anyone knows how to force bing credit to bottom quickmap service, so I don't have legal problems using this service?

Comment: Have you tried to actually export the map from print composer? The logo and disclaimer don't actually show up... by the way, QuickMapServices doesn't have Bing maps - OpenLayers does...

Comment: @DPSSpatial - On the contrary, it does have Bing maps but you need to add them by going to `Web > QuickMapServices > Settings > More services > Get contributed pack` ;)

Answer (score 3):

Bing doesn't seem to include any *credits* when you check its properties:

[image: Bing properties]

So nothing will be shown. **Therefore, just add one yourself!**

---

1. From the menubar, go to:

   ```
   View > Decorations > Copyright Label
   ```

---

2. Add a copyright label like the following and set the placement etc:

   ```
   © 2016 Microsoft
   ```

   [image: Adding copyright label]

   This label can be seen from [Bing Maps](https://www.bing.com/maps):

   [image: Bing Maps]

---

3. And now when you enable it, the copyright should be shown where you set it to:

   [image: Basemap with Copyright label]